# Show that there exists N $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, $a - \frac{\mid a \mid}{2} < a_n < a + \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$ $\forall n>N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let ($a_n$) be a convergent sequence such that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (a_n)$ = a. Show that there exists N $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, $a - \frac{\mid a \mid}{2} < a_n < a + \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$   $\forall n>N$. where $a \neq 0$

I'm not really sure how to go about this question, I can see by maybe some rearranging of the formal definition for the limit of a sequence that $\varepsilon =\frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$ makes this true, but I'm unsure that rearranging the equation and showing that $\varepsilon$ must equal $\frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$ is the correct way to answer the question

Comment: In general, this is false. For example, if $a_n=\frac1n$ (and $a=0$), you can't find such $N$. -- However, if your choice of $\epsilon$ is $>0$, then you get that $N$ **immediately** from the $\epsilon$-definition of limit.

Comment: $\epsilon $ is an arbitrary position real number ,so you just assign it to $\frac{|a|}{2}$since $\frac{|a|}{2}$ is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is nothing to be unsure, it's true.
Since $a\ne 0$,$|\frac{a}{2}|\gt 0$
If you take $\epsilon=\frac{a}{2}$ then there exist a$ N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\forall n\gt N ,,.  |a_n-a|\lt \frac{|a|}{2}\implies -\frac{|a|}{2}\lt a_n -a \lt  \frac{|a|}{2} \implies a-  \frac{\mid a \mid}{2} < a_n < a + \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$$

Comment: I've edited the question to ask what I really meant

Comment: Yes it is enough to just rearrange the terms,as In the given answer. it's the only formal approach .

Comment: Okay excellent thank you!

Comment: I'm new on this

Comment: It's a very good platform to learn math ,mate.